# MATLAB: Remove high frequency noise from wav file

Tags: matlab, audio, filter, signal-processing, wav

I'm trying to remove the high frequency noise from [the following file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1e25QFq7XfEVfrRrRPaQF7hP40B2KWoZ3).

It's a file of a woman reading the news, with a high pitched noise playing loudly over it. Towards the end of the file, someone else begins to speak, but in a different language.

I want to filter out this high pitched noise, and be able to clearly hear the woman reading the news. Looking at the frequency domain:

[image: Unfiltered]

I have tried using a low pass filter, and band stop filter. The bandstop filter produces a signal that no longer has the high pitch ringing, but the audio isn't very clear and it's hard to make out what is being said - the same goes for the low pass filter. I surmise that this is due to me filtering out not only the noise, but the harmonics of the speech as well. It was also necessary that I amplify the audio signal after I filtered it, because it was quieter than before.

Is there some clever way for me to reconstruct the harmonics of the speech in order to hear what is being said more clearly? Or is there a clever way for me to filter the signal without losing too much audio clarity?

I can include any code I used in matlab if needed.

Note:

- I shifted the signal to 0 in the image I linked
- I did use `filtfilt()` instead of `filter()`
- I used `butter()` for the filters

Answer (score 0):

Given the fairly dynamic nature of the interference in your sample, stationary filters are not going to yield very satisfying results. To improve performance, you would need to dynamically adjust the filtering parameters based on estimates of the interference.

Fortunately in this case the interference is pretty strong and exhibits a fairly regular pattern which makes it easier to estimate. This can be seen from the signal's [`spectrogram`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/spectrogram.html). 
For the following derivations we will be assuming the samples of the wavfile has been stored in the array `x` and that the sampling rate is `fs` (which is 8000Hz in the provided sample).

```
[Sx,f,t] = spectrogram(x, triang(1024), 1023, [], fs, 'onesided');
```

[image]

Given that the interference is strong, obtaining the frequency of the interference can be done by locating the peak frequency in each time slice:

```
frequency = zeros(size(Sx,2),1);
for k = 1:size(Sx,2)
    [pks,loc] = findpeaks(Sx(:,k));
    frequency(k) = fs * (loc(1)-1);
end
```

Seeing that the interference is periodic we can use the Discrete Fourier Transform to decompose this signal:

```
M = 32*fs;
Ff = fft(frequency, M);
plot(fs*[0:M-1]/M, 20*log10(abs(Ff));
axis(0, 2);
xlabel('frequency (Hz)');
ylabel('amplitude (dB)');
```

[image]

Using the first two harmonics as an approximation, we can model the frequency of the interference signal as:

```
T = 1.0/fs
t = [0:length(x)-1]*T
freq = 750.0127340203496
       + 249.99913423501602*cos(2*pi*0.25*t - 1.5702946346796276)
       + 250.23974282864816*cos(2*pi*0.5 *t - 1.5701043282285363);
```

At this point we would have enough to create a narrowband filter with a center frequency (which would change dynamically as we keep updating the filter coefficients) given by that frequency model. Note however that constantly recomputing and updating the filter coefficient is a fairly expensive process and given that the interference is strong, it is possible to do better by locking on to the interference phase. This can be done by correlating small blocks of the original signal with sine and cosine at desired frequency. We can then slightly tweak the phase to align the sine/cosine with the original signal.

```
% Compute the phase of the sine/cosine to correlate the signal with
delta_phi = 2*pi*freq/fs;
phi = cumsum(delta_phi);

% We scale the phase adjustments with a triangular window to try to reduce
% phase discontinuities. I've chosen a window of ~200 samples somewhat arbitrarily,
% but it is large enough to cover 8 cycles of the interference around its lowest
% frequency sections (so we can get a better estimate by averaging out other signal
% contributions over multiple interference cycles), and is small enough to capture
% local phase variations.
step = 50;
L    = 200;
win  = triang(L);
win  = win/sum(win);

for i = 0:floor((length(x)-(L-step))/step)
    % The phase tweak to align the sine/cosine isn't linear, so we run a few
    % iterations to let it converge to a phase locked to the original signal
    for iter = 0:1
        xseg   = x[(i*step+1):(i*step+L+1)];
        phiseg = phi[(i*step+1):(i*step+L+1)];
        r1 = sum(xseg .* cos(phiseg));
        r2 = sum(xseg .* sin(phiseg));
        theta = atan2(r2, r1);

        delta_phi[(i*step+1):(i*step+L+1)] = delta_phi[(i*step+1):(i*step+L+1)] - theta*win;
        phi = cumsum(delta_phi);
    end
end
```

Finally, we need to estimate the amplitude of the interference. Here we choose to perform the estimation over the initial 0.15 seconds where there is a little pause before the speech starts so that the estimation is not biased by the speech's amplitude:

```
tmax = 0.15;
nmax = floor(tmax * fs);
amp  = sqrt(2*mean(x[1:nmax].^2));
% this should give us amp ~ 0.250996990794946
```

These parameters then allow us to fairly precisely reconstruct the interference, and correspondingly remove the interference from the original signal by direct subtraction:

```
y = amp * cos(phi)
x = x-y
```

[image]

Listening to the resulting output, you may notice a remaining faint whooshing noise, but nothing compared to the original interference. Obviously this is a fairly ideal case where the parameters of the interference are so easy to estimate that the results almost look too good to be true. You may not get the same performance with more random interference patterns.

*Note*: the python script used for this processing (and the corresponding .wav file output) can be found [here](https://github.com/SleuthEye/SO53324732).

Comment: *Disclaimer*: the answer was provided in Matlab since that was the tag used on the question. However I only had a python environment to perform this processing, so while I tried to transpose it to Matlab's equivalent, there may be cases where things got missed (e.g. based 1 indexing, typos, ...)